# Flex List control more than a String?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface, list

I have a list control where i want to show a string (thats fine) but a colored square as well.

Imagine i have a "add player" button a text input with a color picker. I want to see the color + player name in the List. How could i do this ?

```
[Bindable]
public var data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();  


<mx:List id="eqlist" width="100%" dataProvider="{data}" />



data.addItem(fooTxt.text);
```

This code will only add the text value, should i add a hbox object composed of a colored canvas + text value ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to work with List itemRenderers.
Basically List item renderer (ListItemRenderer) doesn't support a different backgound color per item (backgound color can only be set on List parent).

Example (MXML version - not my favorite way but the simpliest):

Data provider initialization:

```
            var anObject: Object = new Object();
            anObject.label = "my player";
            anObject.backgroundColor = 0xFF0000;
            anObject.color = 0xFFFFFF;
            aData.addItem(anObject);

            anObject = new Object();
            anObject.label = "my player 2";
            anObject.backgroundColor = 0x0000FF;
            anObject.color = 0xAAAAAA;
            aData.addItem(anObject);
```

List display:

```
    <mx:List id="eqlist" width="100%" dataProvider="{aData}" >
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:Canvas backgroundColor="{data.backgroundColor}"
                    color="{data.color}">
                    <mx:Label text="{data.label}">

                    </mx:Label>
                </mx:Canvas>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:List>
```